# Angular: Use Filter and OR Operator Pipe

Tags: angularjs, filter, pipe

Is there a way around using the filter pipe and the OR pipe in an AngularJS expression. For example:

```
{{ price | currency || "no price set" }}
```

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can have what is to be evaluated in parenthesis as:

```
{{ (price | currency) || "no price set" }}
```

so that `no price set` will render when `price | currency` is evaluated as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Although not very readable, that is possible using the ternary operator:

```
{{ price ? (price | currency) : "no price set" }}
```

See **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jroxw3v5/)**

There is one drawback though with the above solution: if the price is defined but equal to zero (assuming that is a valid value for a price in your application), you will get *"no price set"* as zero is *falsy*.
You could solve that by exposing the function `angular.isDefined` to the scope:

```
$scope.isDefined = angular.isDefined;

{{isDefined(price) ? (price | currency) : "no price"}}
```

But, all in all, it will be cleaner to define a custom filter:

```
app.filter('priceFilter', function ($filter) {
  return function (input) {
    return angular.isDefined(input) ? $filter('currency')(input) : 'No price set';
  };
});

{{price | priceFilter}}
```

See **[updated js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jroxw3v5/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I guest you need:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: Array<any>, conditions: {[field: string]: any}): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(item => {
      let allBlanks = true;
      for (let field in conditions) {
        let itemField = item[field] ? item[field].toLowerCase() : '';
        let conditionField = conditions[field] !== undefined ? conditions[field].toLowerCase() : '';
        if(conditionField !== '') {allBlanks = false;}
        if (itemField.indexOf(conditionField) !== -1 && conditionField !== '') {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return allBlanks;
    });
  }

}
```